# Confirm before pressing submit form in symfony and javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony-forms, confirmation

I am have a form built with `FormBuilderInterface`. My code looks:

```
$builder->add('Save',
      SubmitType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'button.save',
                'onSubmit'=> 'return validate()'],
            ]
        );
```

and my validate looks:

```
function validate() {
        if (document.getElementById("status").value === "published") {
            return confirm('Are you sure?');
        }
    }
```

How to prevent saving a form if in confirmation I select `cancel`? Looks like confirm doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out. You have to return false to prevent form from submiting.

```js
function validate() {
  if (document.getElementById("status").value === "published") {
    return confirm('Are you sure?');
  } else {
    console.log('Not Ready');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.google.com" onsubmit="return validate()">

  <input id="status">

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: I added `{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'role': 'form', 'onsubmit':'return validate();'}}) }}` to form and it works.